# Npm with No error Message

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to install packages using npm (including CLI,) but after some point the npm is not responding as such.It is neither showing an error logs nor any error messages. The moment i  enter some package that needs to be installed it's not responding.It goes to the next line without any error message.Can anyone please help me out.Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the logging levels to see if its actually doing something? `npm config set loglevel verbose` or `npm config set loglevel silly` for absolutely everything.

Comment: @Neil Lunn i tried that too still  , i can't access any of the package or rather install package. when i hit npm along with any package which i want to install it does not pop up any thing ,it's blank as such..

Comment: Why are you talking to me? I just corrected the tags on your question (way too many ). Also, no screenshot here. You don't have enough reputation score to do that ( very good thing, don't do it in the future )., Edit your question to include the relevant details. That is what that "edit" link is for. Less noise and more information young padawan.